# What does 为 do in 鸦片战争后，天津开放为通商口岸?

Tags: grammar, usage, meaning-in-context

> 鸦片战争后，天津开放为通商口岸。
>   <sub>[Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/show-%E5%8F%A3%E5%B2%B8-4.html)</sub>

I'm confused about 为 in this example sentence from Jukuu.  I think the sentence means:

> After the Opium Wars, Tianjin opened "treaty ports".

I understand these refer to foreign-run [treaty ports](https://www.chinasage.info/foreign-enclaves.htm), as part of the [unequal treaties](https://military.wikia.org/wiki/Unequal_treaty).  So my guess is that 为 is short for [作为](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BD%9C%E4%B8%BA) = "to act as", but I'm unsure.

**Question**: What does 为 do in 鸦片战争后，天津开放为通商口岸?

Comment: Yes,  为 = 作为 = "to be"  or "as" here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[为](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%B8%BA) means 变成 / 成为 here.

> (7) 变成，成为 [become]
>
> 何遽不为福。——《淮南子·人间训》
>
> 不能为祸。
>
> 终为忠臣。——《世说新语·自新》
>
> 而改为入。——宋· 洪迈《容斋续笔》

The sentence means *Tianjin (was) opened and became treaty port*.